# Entity Framework Core: Fluent api many-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I model the following: a user has many followers and follows many users. The same user has many blocked users (Twitter kinda feature).

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Following { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> BlockedUsers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Follower { get; set; }
    public string FollowerId { get; set; }
}
```

My implementation so far:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.FollowerId });

    builder.HasOne(l => l.User)
           .WithMany(a => a.Followers)
           .HasForeignKey(l => l.UserId);

    builder.HasOne(l => l.Follower)
           .WithMany(a => a.Following)
           .HasForeignKey(l => l.FollowerId);
}
```

How do I implement the blocked users field?

```
public virtual ICollection<User> BlockedUsers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have a `User` and and `ApplicationUser`? What is the `User` class for?

Comment: `User` seems to be a many-to-many link entity representing Follower / Following links. Hence for Blocked / Blocking link you need a *separate* similar link entity.

Comment: @DavidKemp like Ivan said, User is a link, it acts like a [join](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) table. ApplicationUser is a class that extends IdentyUser and adds extra property (Columns) to the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: It's probably work reviewing the documentation on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many, but like @IvanStoev said, you need another `class` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in chat, I rarely trust EF's capabilities for Many-to-Many, nevermind EF Core. This isn't a direct to your question but instead explains how I'd handle this if it were my project.

You have your `ApplicationUser` already, so the tables that come off them would only exist to define the relationships between differing `ApplicationUsers`. Each User can have multiple everything: Followers, Following, and Blocked. A user is not directly in control of who follows them though, so that doesn't need its own table. You can determine who follows a user by looking at the Follower table.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserFollow> Following { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserFollow> Followers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserBlock> BlockedUsers { get; set; }
}

public class UserFollow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SourceUserId))]
    public ApplicationUser SourceUser { get; set; }
    public string SourceUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FollowedUserId))]
    public ApplicationUser FollowedUser { get; set; }
    public string FollowedUserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserBlock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SourceUserId))]
    public ApplicationUser SourceUser { get; set; }
    public string SourceUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BlockedUserId))]
    public ApplicationUser BlockedUser { get; set; }
    public string BlockedUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Your configuration then doesn't change much (consider this psuedo, untested):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    moderlBuilder.Entity<UserFollow>()
           .HasOne(l => l.SourceUser)
           .WithMany(a => a.Following)
           .HasForeignKey(l => l.SourceUserId);

    moderlBuilder.Entity<UserFollow>()
           .HasOne(l => l.FollowedUser)
           .WithMany(a => a.Followers)
           .HasForeignKey(l => l.FollowedUserId);

    moderlBuilder.Entity<UserBlock>()
           .HasOne(l => l.SourceUser)
           .WithMany(a => a.BlockedUsers)
           .HasForeignKey(l => l.SourceUserId);
}
```

(note I've always whacked on a simple key (`Id` just for ease of querying) but you can change it back to be composite as needed)

Comment: How I naming properties in Likes Table? Liker & Liking or what??